# Tracking variable or memory change in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, watchpoint

Is there any way to track variable changes or memory changes in Xcode? I'm looking for functionality like Visual Studio's data breakpoint.

I want to know where my object's view frame is being changed. I want to set a breakpoint at a member variable and run it. Then I could determine where it's changed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Xcode uses `gdb` (or `lldb`, but that's another story) to implement its debugging functionality. `gdb` has the ability to set hardware watchpoints and hence so does Xcode.

[This](http://scottmcpeak.com/memory-errors/) is a useful page for generic debugging of memory errors. Xcode's debugging console window is really just a `gdb` shell, you can type in commands as you please. The ever-helpful Quinn Taylor explains how to do so in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040585/watching-variables-in-xcode/1042298#1042298) related post.

If you'd rather avoid interacting with `gdb` directly, you can right-click a variable in Xcode's debugging window and select "Watch Variable". Xcode will then alert you whenever your variable's value has been changed.

Comment: Appreciate for the detail answer! I'll try!

Comment: Never thought to right click on the variables in the watch window! Now to hope it actually hits it ;) Seems ropey enough just displaying variable values — telling me local vars are out of scope is really not helpful

Comment: @LaceySnr: check my answer. I have the same problem with XCode watch. That's why I am using gdb watchpoint.

Comment: "watchpoints not supported" is what I get when trying this on Xcode 5.

Comment: tl;dr right-click variable and click "Watch Variable"

Comment: More specifically, Xcode will tell you: "error: Watchpoint creation failed ... watch size of [X] is not supported."

Answer (score 13):

You can use [hardware watchpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

You have to get the address of the variable you want to track (type `p &my_var` in gdb prompt).

It will print somehting like `0x12345678`.

- With gdb: type `watch *(int *)0x12345678`.
- With lldb: `watch set expression (int *)0x12345678` (or `w s e (int *)0x12345678`)

This assumes your variable is an `int`. It will create an hardware watchpoint on this address.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Under the Run menu there is "Debugger" which provides a visual frontend to gdb.

Also, there is a breakpoint button next to the Build and Run button. You can click that and manage your breakpoints under Run > Manage Breakpoints.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what he's looking for. You are talking about standard breakpoints, but he is talking about breaking when data stored at a location in memory changes. More like a watchpoint than a breakpoint.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, I don't know if there are any "triggers" like that. However, through the Debugger and use of standard breakpoints you can see the data changing. Probably not as smooth as Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but in case you are still wondering I posted a detailed answer here: [In XCode 6 how can you set a watchpoint without stopping execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581844/in-xcode-6-how-can-you-set-a-watchpoint-without-stopping-execution/28600716#28600716)