# debug variable in xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

A variable in my code is being de-allocated somewhere, and i don't know where. I'm trying to debug it, but there is a lot of code to search through.

> Is there a way to follow a variable, and show where it is being modified?

Comment: Is that variable accessed using a property? If so, override the setter and add a breakpoint into it. If it is not a property, make it one. Also make sure that all assignment is done via the setter.

Comment: You could probably use conditional breakpoints. It is described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988621/how-to-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-in-xcode-based-on-an-object-string-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the variable in XCode's debugging window, and select "Watch variable".

Alternatively, use gdb:
http://scottmcpeak.com/memory-errors/

This is discussed here in a similar topic:
[Tracking variable or memory change in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801175/tracking-variable-or-memory-change-in-xcode)

Comment: That would be the **right** way of doing it. From my experience however, this failed a lot. Maybe I should give it another shot, now that gdb commonly isnt used anymore.

Comment: doesnt seem to be working for me. after i clik on watch "variable" and then click on continue execution, i dont see the variable anymore.i need to figure out which line of code is resetting the variable to nil. variable is supposed to hold an AGSMapView