# Xcode LLDB watchpoints

Tags: xcode, gdb, lldb

Is there any way to watch a variable in Xcode using LLDB ? Or is this only possible with GDB ?
I'm trying to use the command `watchpoint set variable` but I get the message:

> invalid command 'watchpoint set'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Watchpoints are supported for iOS and Mac OS X debugging as of Xcode 4.5.  To set a breakpoint on a variable named `foo`, do

```
(lldb) watchpoint set variable foo
```

you can always use the shortest unambiguous name for commands in the lldb console so

```
(lldb) w s v foo
```

would also work here.

In Xcode, in the locals window you can right-click/control-click on variables and you'll have an option to set a watchpoint on it.

The current arm and x86 cpus only support 4 watchpoints being active at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know that they have been activated . I have checked on XCode 4.5 and it works!

Comment: and where can these watched variables be seen?

Comment: `watch list` will list all watched variables.  See `help watch` for other supported subcommands.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
frame variable -w
```

instead. The 'watchpoint set' command is in lldb's development branch, and will likely make it in to a future version of Xcode.

For example:

```
frame variable -w write myvar
```

EDIT: The `watch set variable` syntax mentioned in the original post is now supported in lldb in XCode 4.4 and greater.

Comment: A reverence which includes the `watch set var -w write global_var` format:  http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html