# Finding the first write to a variable in LLDB

Tags: c++, clang, breakpoints, lldb, watchpoint

I'm debugging a large program using LLDB and there's one `bool` variable that's used everywhere, generally referenced as an extern. I've been debugging it for a while and, no matter where I set my breakpoints, the value is always `true`. I'd like to find where this value is set - I've tried searching the code and setting breakpoints at every assignment of that variable but none of those seem to get triggered, and at a later breakpoint that value is always `true`. Is there any way of pinpointing the first write to a variable?

Comment: See “[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199421/xcode-lldb-watchpoints][1].”                                   


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199421/xcode-lldb-watchpoints

Answer (score 1):

Like Flash Sheridan noted in his comment to your question, you want to use a watchpoint here.  Set a breakpoint early in your app (e.g. `NSApplicationMain`), set a watchpoint on your (presumably global) bool variable,

```
(lldb) watch set variable myvar
```

or

```
(lldb) w s v myvar
```

and this should stop program execution every time `myvar` is modified.