# Obj-c let me  change the class of a variable, and its bad: How hunt it?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, types, ios4, xcode4

Well, in obj-c have the ability of change the class of a declared var. So if I declare myVar as a `NSString`, is possible to get back later a `NSNUmber`.

I have this problem now, but I can't find where in my code is the identity swap... exist a way to find it? For example is possible to set a breakpoint where `[myVar class] == [NSString class]` and when change know it?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040585/watching-variables-in-xcode or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801175/tracking-variable-or-memory-change-in-xcode

Answer (score 3):

You may be confused about the *static* type of a pointer, and the *actual* type of the object it points to. Consider this code:

```
NSString *test = @"test";
NSNumber *notReallyANumber = (NSNumber *)test;
```

This is *valid* code, but it didn't "transform" test into an NSNumber. It's still a string, just with an incorrect type on the pointer.

Basically, no, you don't have the ability to change the class of a variable (you do, but it's deep deep magic and almost never occurs).

Comment: I think he has another problem: An assignment which shouldn't happen. An @macmcx tries to locate the statement, which performs the assignment.

Comment: Yes that is the thing. And the typecast could be the issue, the problem is detect when... I could review all the code but hope exist a less time consuming option..